# GridView DataBind does not work

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview

I am using ASP.NET Membership and Linq. I have a problem here: I show all users inside a grid view that has a delete button. Take a look at this code:

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="UsersGridView" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="UsersLinqDataSource" 
    AllowPaging="True">

    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="UserName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastActivityDate" HeaderText="LastActivityDate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LastActivityDate" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteButton_Click"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:LinqDataSource 
    ID="UsersLinqDataSource" 
    runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="TraceWeb.DataModel.DataContextDataContext" 
    EntityTypeName="" 
    Select="new (UserName, LastActivityDate)" 
    TableName="Users" 
    EnableDelete="True">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

And Delete button's event handler:

```
protected void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String username = (String)((sender as IButtonControl).CommandArgument);
    Membership.DeleteUser(username, true);
    UsersGridView.DataBind();
}
```

But problem is that after running this code and deleting a user, GridView still shows that user.

Comment: Are you sure that `Membership.DeleteUser` deletes the record? Maybe it is marking it as deleted?

Comment: @AmiramKorach: [MSDN `Membership.DeleteUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6b0zxdw.aspx): _"Deletes a user from the database"_

Comment: Membership deletes the User and if I reload the page, GridView does not show that user, so I think that user is actually deleted.

Comment: The user is deleted from database. So the problem is that I delete User from Membership not Linq? And if so, what should I do to notify linq about new changes?

Comment: Never used a LinqDataSource control. But [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.enabledelete.aspx) says: _"The LinqDataSource control does not support automatic delete operations **when the Select property or the GroupBy property is set. In that case, the LinqDataSource control throws an exception if a delete operation is tried.**"_ So i  assume that you're getting an exception and you should either set `EnableDelete` to false or to remove the select then.

Comment: UsersGridView.databind before setup , UsersGridView try refresh  (UsersGridView.Datasource=null)datasource.

Comment: it seems ugly but adding this line `UsersLinqDataSource.DataBind();` before `UsersGridView.DataBind();` solved the problem! Any idea?

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad: The fact is that `UsersGridView.DataBind()` only binds the EXISTING data in DataSource to the GridView. The existing data is the one the system got before the update. The DataSource is not updated automatically after deletion. `UsersLinqDataSource.DataBind()` binds data to the data source; this causes the information to update to the actual values (after deletion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `Membership` and `UsersLinqDataSource` are not connected and if you "refresh" the `UsersLinqDataSource` status and then rebind your grid, all will be displayed properly.

```
protected void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String username = (String)((sender as IButtonControl).CommandArgument);
    Membership.DeleteUser(username, true);

    // first solution: may not work properly
    UsersLinqDataSource = yourLinqData;

    // second solution: work
    UsersLinqDataSource = null;
    UsersLinqDataSource = yourLinqData;

    UsersGridView.DataBind();
}
```